# Reason for drop in REIT ETFs over last couple weeks

Tags: united-states, etf, current-events, reit

Since the beginning of the year, it seems that most REIT ETFs have dropped around 5% (e.g., IYR) while stocks have done really well.

Were there any market/economic/political events recently that caused the price of REITs to go down?

Given that 5% is a significant drop, there should be some rational and objective explanation for it.  I tried Googling for news about REITs, but you just get a bunch of sites with no useful content.

For a particular example, let's use [IYR](https://finance.google.com/finance?q=NYSEARCA%3AIYR) which is traded in the US.

Comment: Are you including the end of 2017 and considering the end of year dividend?

Comment: @user662852, good question, but the dividend was mid December so not related to that.

Comment: You might want to qualify which markets you are referring to. REITs trade on a number of exchanges in a number of countries around the world.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea, I had mentioned IYR, but edited the question to make it a more explicit example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to give an objective answer to this question. REITs tend to behave more like bonds than like stocks. The expectation of rising interest rates, as well as a general "risk on" mood, could explain the underperformance. The effects of tax reform might also affect REITs.

Comment: Yes, I expect you are right, but I was hoping there might be a more satisfactory explanation.  I also noticed today that nearly all trading of IYR is at market open/close so I suspect that the trading is mostly by firms/institutions and very little by individual investors.